# How can I make this aggregation query more efficient?

Tags: sql-server-2014, optimization

I have a query that's taking quite a long time on my machine (7 minutes) to execute and I was wondering whether I could make it (significantly) quicker:

```
SELECT
    rec.[Id] AS RecordId,
    MIN(rec.[CreationDate]) AS RecordCreationDate,
    MIN(rec.[LastModified]) AS RecordLastModified,
    MIN(rec.[AssetType]) AS RecordAssetType,
    MIN(rec.[MasterFilename]) AS RecordMasterFilename,
    MIN(rec.[GameName]) AS RecordGameName,
    usr.[OrganizationName],
    COUNT(hist.[Id]) AS TimesDownloaded
FROM
(
    SELECT
        innerRec.Id,
        MIN(innerRec.CreationDate) AS CreationDate,
        MIN(innerRec.LastModified) AS LastModified,
        MIN(innerRec.AssetType) AS AssetType,
        MIN(innerRec.MasterFilename) AS MasterFilename,
        MIN(innerRec.GameName) AS GameName
    FROM
        [dbo].[Record] innerRec INNER JOIN [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink] innerLnk ON innerRec.Id = innerLnk.RecordId
    -- WHERE (classification ID is foo or bar)
    GROUP BY
        innerRec.Id
    -- HAVING COUNT(innerLnk.ClassificationId) = (number of specified classifications)
) rec
CROSS JOIN
    [dbo].[AdamUser] usr
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory] WHERE [CreatedOn] > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND [CreatedOn] < '2016-12-01 00:00:00') hist ON usr.Name = hist.AccessingUser AND rec.Id = hist.RecordId
GROUP BY
    rec.Id, usr.OrganizationName
```

What it's doing is extracting data to be put in an Excel spreadsheet report (whether a spreadsheet is a good presentation of this data is outside the scope of this question :-) )

The first subquery pulls out records optionally filtered by a list of classification IDs.  These are then cross joined with the user table, because each user table row actually contains the info we really need for this: the user's organization name.  I then left join the maintenance job history table (storing an entry for each record download) in order to create multiple rows if a record has been accessed multiple times, then group by record ID and organization name to get a "number of record downloads per organization" count as `TimesDownloaded`.

The code that is reading this output then populates an associative array whose key is `OrganizationName` and whose value is `TimesDownloaded`, creating the equivalent of a dynamic `PIVOT` where each record row contains one column per organization each containing the count of the number of record downloads.

As you can imagine this runs quite slowly on a large dataset, as I said above; the one I'm working with has ~38000 `Record`s and ~1000 users, meaning the cross join results in ~38,000,000 rows, but it seems conceptually necessary.

Can this be made significantly more efficient?  Would it be better if I did the `PIVOT` in dynamic SQL instead?

The DBMS I'm using is SQL Server 2014.

Here are the schema definitions for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdamUser](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [UserGroupName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_AdamUser_Name] ON [dbo].[AdamUser]
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AccessingUser] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MaintenanceJobHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MaintenanceJobHistory_CreatedOn] ON [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory]
(
    [CreatedOn] ASC
)
INCLUDE (     [Id],
    [RecordId],
    [AccessingUser]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Record](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AssetType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MasterFilename] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [GameName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Record] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ClassificationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RecordClassificationLink] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here's the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy6LlXDXg

Typical output:
[image: Typical output]

However this output gets turned into an Excel spreadsheet along the lines of the following by the calling program (hence its being like a `PIVOT` operation):

```
.----------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Filename | Creation Date | #times downloaded by: CompanyA | CompanyB | ...
| foo.png  | 1/2/3         |                       0        | 2        |
| bar.png  | 1/3/4         |                       3        | 1        |
...
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I ended up making things significantly more efficient by moving the `PIVOT` operation into the SQL query itself; that way, SQL Server only has to output the number of rows in the `Record` table rather than that multiplied by the number of organizations (not too bad until you get to hundreds of organizations, at which point it's a huge number).  The operation still takes a few minutes, but it's much more bearable.  Here's the query I finally decided to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        rec.[Id]                         AS RecordId,
        'Org_' + usr.[OrganizationName]  AS OrganizationNamePrefixed,
        COUNT(hist.[Id])                 AS TimesDownloaded  -- To be aggregated by PIVOT
    FROM (
        SELECT
            innerRec.[Id]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Record] innerRec
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink] innerLnk ON innerLnk.[RecordId] = innerRec.[Id]
        -- WHERE (classification ID is foo or bar), for optional classification filtering
        GROUP BY
            innerRec.[Id]
        -- HAVING COUNT(innerLnk.ClassificationId) = (number of specified classifications), for optional classification filtering
    ) rec
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AdamUser] usr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory] WHERE [CreatedOn] > 'eg. 2016-01-01 12:00:00' AND [CreatedOn] < 'eg. 2016-12-01 12:00:00'
    ) hist ON hist.[AccessingUser] = usr.[Name] AND hist.[RecordId] = rec.[Id]
    GROUP BY
        rec.[Id], usr.[OrganizationName]
) srcTable
PIVOT  -- Pivot around columns outside aggregation fn, eg. heading column [OrganizationNamePrefixed] & all other columns: [RecordId]
(
    MIN(srcTable.[TimesDownloaded]) FOR [OrganizationNamePrefixed] IN (...list of ~200 columns dynamically generated...)
) pivotTable
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Record] outerRec ON outerRec.[Id] = pivotTable.[RecordId]
```

I added various indexes and also made the `PIVOT` as efficient as possible by only selecting the aggregation column, the headings column, and the necessary other column(s) to pivot around.  Lastly, I re-`JOIN` the `Record` table using the `RecordId` PK to get the extra record info per row.

Comment: Can you give an example of the results you expect? Is it a "cross tab" of Records and Users? (with "Number of downloads" or null as the sum that appears in each cell?)

Comment: Try with `option (querytraceon 4199, querytraceon 9481)` --> Enable all optimizer fixes and use legacy CE. I see it using parallelism and hash join with good seeks & no spool operator. I dont have the data to play, but using fake stats with `ROWCOUNT=10000000` I am getting better plan. Obviously, adding appropriate indexes will give it more boost.

Comment: Sorry .. I see table spool .. but I would still test out with the trace flags as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stuff that is probably taking a lot of time is a large number of `Sort` operations in your query plan. You can preempt those by sorting the data yourself, in the form of indexes.

Here are some index suggestions that I think would get you started:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_RecordId
    ON dbo.RecordClassificationLink (RecordId);

CREATE INDEX IX_MaintenanceJobHistory_ByUser
    ON dbo.MaintenanceJobHistory (AccessingUser, RecordId);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_AdamUser_OrgnName
    ON dbo.AdamUser (OrganizationName, Name);
```

Then, you could modify your query a little bit to help the optimizer make some smart choices, like aggregating certain data streams before they're joined and create a much larger product that will take more time to aggregate:

```
SELECT
    rec.[Id] AS RecordId,
    MIN(rec.[CreationDate]) AS RecordCreationDate,
    MIN(rec.[LastModified]) AS RecordLastModified,
    MIN(rec.[AssetType]) AS RecordAssetType,
    MIN(rec.[MasterFilename]) AS RecordMasterFilename,
    MIN(rec.[GameName]) AS RecordGameName,
    usr.[OrganizationName],
    SUM(ISNULL(hist._count, 0)) AS TimesDownloaded
FROM
(
    SELECT
        innerRec.Id,
        MIN(innerRec.CreationDate) AS CreationDate,
        MIN(innerRec.LastModified) AS LastModified,
        MIN(innerRec.AssetType) AS AssetType,
        MIN(innerRec.MasterFilename) AS MasterFilename,
        MIN(innerRec.GameName) AS GameName
    FROM [dbo].[Record] innerRec
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink] innerLnk ON innerRec.Id = innerLnk.RecordId
    -- WHERE (classification ID is foo or bar)
    GROUP BY
        innerRec.Id
    -- HAVING COUNT(innerLnk.ClassificationId) = (number of specified classifications)
) AS rec
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AdamUser] AS usr
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AccessingUser, RecordId, COUNT(*) AS _count
     FROM [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory]
     WHERE [CreatedOn] > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND
           [CreatedOn] < '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
     GROUP BY AccessingUser, RecordId
    ) AS hist ON
        usr.Name = hist.AccessingUser AND
        rec.Id = hist.RecordId
GROUP BY
    rec.Id, usr.OrganizationName;
```

I've done the following:

- the `hist` subquery is aggregated on `AccessingUser, RecordId`, and I've created a `COUNT(*) AS _count`. This query uses the new index `IX_MaintenanceJobHistory_ByUser` to perform very efficiently without any memory grant or hash tables.
- Because of this, I've replaced `COUNT(hist.Id)` with `SUM(ISNULL(hist._count, 0)) AS TimesDownloaded`
- The new index on `dbo.RecordClassificationLink` helps perform a smooth join with the `Record` table, but if you add your `WHERE` and `HAVING`, that index won't help you.
- The new index on `dbo.AdamUser` also improves performance by eliminating a Sort operator - because you aggregate on the `OrganizationName` column, might as well have your data sorted on this from the get-go.

In my mind, that should give you the same result, but it's late here, so you'll have to verify the results yourself. :)

Here's my query plan:
[image: First plan]

**EDIT**: You could also simplify the `rec` part a bit - probably be a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT
    rec.[Id] AS RecordId,
    rec.[CreationDate] AS RecordCreationDate,
    rec.[LastModified] AS RecordLastModified,
    rec.[AssetType] AS RecordAssetType,
    rec.[MasterFilename] AS RecordMasterFilename,
    rec.[GameName] AS RecordGameName,
    usr.[OrganizationName],
    SUM(ISNULL(hist._count, 0)) AS TimesDownloaded
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        CreationDate,
        LastModified,
        AssetType,
        MasterFilename,
        GameName
    FROM [dbo].[Record]
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT RecordId
        FROM [dbo].[RecordClassificationLink]
        --- WHERE ClassificationId=...
        )
) AS rec
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[AdamUser] AS usr
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AccessingUser, RecordId, COUNT(*) AS _count
     FROM [dbo].[MaintenanceJobHistory]
     WHERE [CreatedOn] > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND
           [CreatedOn] < '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
     GROUP BY AccessingUser, RecordId
    ) AS hist ON
        usr.Name = hist.AccessingUser AND
        rec.Id = hist.RecordId
GROUP BY
    usr.OrganizationName,
    rec.[Id],
    rec.[CreationDate],
    rec.[LastModified],
    rec.[AssetType],
    rec.[MasterFilename],
    rec.[GameName],
    usr.[OrganizationName];
```

... and the plan looks a tiny bit better as well (look for the red `Lazy spool` at the bottom of the original plan, that is now gone.)

[image: New plan]

Comment: `IX_RecordId` is invalid because that column isn't guaranteed to be unique; records can have multiple classifications.

Comment: Ah, of course. I've changed it to non-unique. Doesn't really affect the plan.

Comment: Daniel, FYI : http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162801/1186